# Limit ssh public key to git only

Tags: ssh, security, git, restrictions

I want to restrict the capabilities of the users connecting through ssh to my server. 
Besides giving those users limited permissions, I want to add an extra layer of security as explained in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/836637/restrict-ssh-key-to-only-execute-rsync) (and the guide linked in it).

The users must be able only to send the three following commands:

```
git clone username@<path of a given repository>
git push
git pull
```

I tried the code of the linked question but I can't do the same for git. It refuses to connect and trying to print `${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}` for the command `git clone ...` its value reads

```
git-upload-pack <path of a given repository>
```

and not `git clone ...` anymore. Maybe this is the problem.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Linked question?

Comment: Projects like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) provide a [script](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell) to handle security like this.

Comment: @Attie fixed, sorry